# Nuxt Can't access server on asyncData with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, axios, nuxt.js

I've created this boilerplate REDACTED that I'm using on another project and I'm unable to fetch data with `asyncData` it returns

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 80,
  ...
```

My code looks like this:

```
  async asyncData ({ $axios, store, req }) {
    const userEmail = 'mail@mail.com'

    await $axios
      .post(`${process.env.BASE_API_URL}/profilepage`, {
        email: userEmail
      })
      .then((resp) => {
        store.commit('setUser', resp.data.user)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  },
```

the `BASE_API_URL` it's `BASE_API_URL=http://localhost/api` I've tried also with `http://webserver:80/api/profilepage` but no luck.

How can I fix it and be able to fecth data also on the server side? As you can see I have a redirect on the webserver service that points to the Laravel container if match `api|storage` REDACTED

Comment: your example is not reproducible from the repository you have attached. I'v cloned your repo and used `docker-compose up -d` but many services are not starting so it's not clear where is the problem with the communication.

Comment: as I said that's the base i've started the project I'm working on, if you want to start that repo you need to do some manual setup, something I've automated in the other project. Anyway...using this or the other repo I can't use the above script to fetch data in `asyncData`. I can do it when I do it on a mounted hook for example but not on the server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem even though TBH I don't get the logic.
in the `docker-compose.yml` I have changed port `80:81` in `80:80` and the `nginx.conf` to use 80 instead of 81 and now I can use http://webserver/api/... and access the endpoint when on the server side.